# in PHP, what is the difference between trader_ma and trader_sma?

Tags: php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.trader.php

basically, what's the difference between simple moving average and moving average ?

Comment: `sma` is a shortcut for `ma` using the `SMA` type.

Comment: you don't have the option for `mAType` with the `trader_sma`

Comment: so, basically same thing? [ that's why I asked first place =P ]   thanks

Answer (score 2):

Appreciate this answer is a little tardy, but for for the benefit of others who may find this question:

There are different "types" of moving average algorithms. They place different weightings on each of the values used to calculate the mean, e.g.

- Simple moving average (PHP: TRADER_MA_TYPE_SMA)
- Weighted moving average (PHP: TRADER_MA_TYPE_WMA)
- Exponential moving average (PHP: TRADER_MA_TYPE_EMA)

Have a read of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

(The PHP constants are defined: http://php.net/manual/en/trader.constants.php)

If you use trader_ma, then you should explicitly specify the type of moving average. E.g. for simple moving average:

```
trader_ma ( $real , $timePeriod , TRADER_MA_TYPE_SMA )
```

Using trader_sma implies that you are using TRADER_MA_TYPE_SMA

```
trader_sma ( $real , $timePeriod )
```